# Last 7 deliveries

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How to get last 7 deliveries that were made to a customer?
[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Tried:

```
select customer ID, Package ID, date,
row_number() over (partition by customer id, package id order by date desc) as nth delivery
from data
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In the previous version of your sample data, there was a column `Delivery Status` by which we could know if the package was delivered or not, according to your current sample data, how could we know that? i.e. B has two rows of data; which one is holding the delivery date?

Comment: Don't partition by package.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks for the comment. But may I know why?

Comment: Because you want all of the deliveries for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

select * from (    select customer ID, package Id,
row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date desc, package id ) as nth delivery
from data)a
where a.nth delivery between 1 and 7

Comment: This will not give you the required numbering, you need to add a where clause to set a condition on the `Delivery Status` column, also what about the requirement of *How to get last 7 deliveries that were made to a customer?*

Comment: Thanks for the question. I have updated the query to give last 7 deliveries. You are right. To filter only "delivered" entries, where clause should be introduced. But I updated the question an hour ago. Hope the answer is correct for the updated scenario

Comment: In the updated scenario you have two rows for A and two rows for B, according to what you want to get two rows for A and one for B.

Comment: you are right. Expected result is 2 rows of A and 2 rows of B. I have updated the expected result and also included date column to show how the recent delivered package takes first row number '1'